# Magento Admin broken and nonsensical characters appearing after move

Tags: magento, character-encoding, migration

I am fairly a beginner at the Magento platform and have built a store on a shared hosting environment. I have just migrated this Magento store to a local server and will be hosting the website from that server. I am using the Bitnami Magento Stack.

I can get the frontend to display, however, my products are not displaying. I have attempted to login to the administrator panel, however, I get several errors upon trying to login (see screenshots).

[image: Screenshot 1]

[Screenshot 2 http://s1.postimg.org/xdwffejzf/Screen_Shot_2014_12_28_at_7_30_50_PM.jpg](http://s1.postimg.org/xdwffejzf/Screen_Shot_2014_12_28_at_7_30_50_PM.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you need to update each time you move a single-store Magento site from one computer to the other. Not taking these actions will cause the problems you are seeing now:

1. app/etc/local.xml
   You need to update the host, username, password, and the db name (if it has changed from the other host). The username and password you are specifying here are the username and password of your mysql user. Here is the specific section you are looking for:

   ```
           <connection>
               <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
               <username><![CDATA[db_username]]></username>
               <password><![CDATA[db_user_password]]></password>
               <dbname><![CDATA[db_name]]></dbname>
               <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
               <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
               <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
               <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
               <active>1</active>
           </connection>
   ```
2. core_config_data
   core_config_data is a table in your magento database. You need to log in to mysql, use the magento database, and find the rows where the secure and insecure base urls are specified. You can find these rows with the line

   ```
   select * from core_config_data where path like "%base_url";
   ```

   You can then use the "config_id" values to update the value to the correct url. For example, I have a sight hosted locally on mm.localhost and the config_id from the core_config_data table for web/unsecure/base_url is 6. I would do the command:

   ```
   update core_config_data set value='http://mm.localhost/' where config_id=6;
   ```